# Don't see all constructors in intellisense

Tags: c#

I need to create different parameter patterns: for example;
in case i need an instance of the object struct Student() with parameters {string username,string password} or the same struct Student() with parameters {string email,string phonenumber,string password};

i have tried to implement it by creating Two constructors for the same class Student but it does not Work. It only Provides Parameter provisions for the first constructor.

```
 public struct student
{
    private string username;
    private string password;

    public string Username
    {
        get { return username; }
        set { username = value; }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set { password = value; }
    }

    public student(string username, string password)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;

    }

    public student(string username,string email,string phonenumber,string password)
    {
        this.password = password;
        this.username = email;
    }
}
```

This is what it Provides;

[1 of 2 options for the parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRcH7.png)

[2 of 2 options for the parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1h7T.png)

Comment: "it only provides parameter provisions" <-- what is "it"? what is "parameter provisions"? Please explain what the problem is more because what you've done looks ok other than the fact that you don't have properties for phonenumber and email.

Comment: Use a class instead of a struct for this, also follow .NET capitalization conventions. Apart from that, i've tried your code and i get all constructors in intellisense.

Comment: The images does not match the shown code. Please update.

Comment: It works fine.  I just tried your code. Don't use a struct though - its a class

Comment: Try a clean build, should fix the issue.

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter  Your Work Around works best..Thanks Alot

Answer (score 1):

If you're scratching your head thinking what people mean by comments left, here is what (give or take) it should look like:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public Student(string username, string password)
    {
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
    }

    public Student(string username, string email, string phoneNumber, string password)
    {
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
        Email = email;
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

Or the overloaded constructor can look like this:

```
public Student(string username, string email, string phoneNumber, string password) : this (username, password)
{
    Email = email;
    PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is answer but i'd split your working code into two classes and would also use [auto-implemented properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) :

```
public class LoginInfo
{
    public string Username { get; private set; }
    public string Password { get; private set; } 

    private LoginInfo() {}

    public LoginInfo(string login, string password)
    {
        this.Login = login; 
        this.Password = password;
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public LoginInfo Logindata { get; private set; }
    public string PhoneNumber  { get; private set; }

    public student(string username, string password)
    {
        logindata = new LoginInfo(username, password);
    }

    public student(string email, string password, string phonenumber)
    {
        logindata = new LoginInfo(email, password);
        PhoneNumber = phonenumber;
    }
}
```

Note how we use `private set` to make our properties setter unreachable from outside of the class. Also mind that correct naming is important as well. If you give name to property or a class normally it starts with Upper case and if it is field then from lowercase or underscore _